# Rewrite rule for angular

Tags: angular, mod-rewrite

I am trying to setup a rewrite rule for an angular app for a captive portal. Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/guest/s/(.*)$
RewriteRule . /index.html [QSA,L]
```

The captive portal gets accessed with `https://example.com/guest/s/xxx/?id=...`
The problem now is, that after loading of the page, the usl gets changed to `https://example.com` without any parameters, which I need. How do I need setup this, that no change of the url is happening?

Comment: instead of setting base in `.htaccess` , please set it in angular using `--base-href` and then use normal rewrite rules http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: @JoelJoseph thanks for your response. the problem with this solution is (if I understand it right), that the base url is variable, so it ca be ```/guest/s/xxx/``` or ```/guest/s/yyy/```. How can I handle this?

Comment: Ok, if someone has the same problem, I have found a solution which works fine described on this site: [https://medium.com/@anandshende1994/setting-base-href-dynamically-in-angular-6-b7fe824848cf](https://medium.com/@anandshende1994/setting-base-href-dynamically-in-angular-6-b7fe824848cf)